# encoding java Double as asn1 Real {sign, mantissa, base, exponent}

Tags: java, asn.1

I have implemented my own ASN.1 framework and my last item is encoding a Java Double as an ASN.1 Real. First link is my library, then a link to the spec on ASN.1 Reals. My issue in in my encodeDoubleValue in accessing the correct mantissa. Help!

```
https://github.com/ZiroZimbarra/ASN1
```

https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A41%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22FitH%22%7D%2C519%5D

My code in my test for Reals looks like this:

```
testRealBytes(new byte[] {9, 5, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x55}, 1398101.25);
```

here is my test implementation, where my issue occurs in encoding on the thrid line of code.

```
    private void testRealBytes(byte[] bytes, Object testObj) throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object obj = (Double) ASN1InputStream.decode(bytes);
    assertTrue(obj.equals(testObj));
    byte[] newBytes = ASN1OutputStream.encodeObject(obj);
    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(bytes, newBytes));
}
```

Here is my encodeValue method:

```
    public void encodeDoubleValue(Double doubleObj, ASN1OutputStream derStream) throws IOException {
    if(doubleObj == 0) {return; }
    if(doubleObj == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) { derStream.write(0x40); return; }
    if(doubleObj == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) { derStream.write(0x41); return; }
    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(doubleObj);
    long mantissa = (bits & 0x000fffffffffffffL);
    int exponent = Integer.valueOf(Long.valueOf(((bits & 0x7FF0000000000000L) >> 52) - 1023).toString());
    int base = 2;
    byte signByte = (byte) (((bits & 0x8000000000000000L) > 1) ? 0x40 : 0x00);
    ASN1OutputStream exponentStream = derStream.newStream();
    new ASN1IntegerType().encodeValue(exponent, exponentStream);
    byte[] exponentBytes = exponentStream.toByteArray();
    switch(exponentBytes.length) {
        case 1: 
            derStream.write(0x80 | (byte) signByte | 0x00);
            break;
        case 2:
            derStream.write(0x80 | (byte) signByte | 0x01);
            break;
        case 3:
            derStream.write(0x80 | (byte) signByte | 0x02);
            break;
        default:
            derStream.write(0x80 | (byte) signByte | 0x03);
            derStream.write(exponentBytes.length);
            break;
    }
    derStream.write(exponentBytes);

    byte[] leftBytes = Long.toUnsignedString(mantissa, 16).getBytes();
    int length = leftBytes.length;
    byte[] mantissaBytes = new byte[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        mantissaBytes[i] = leftBytes[length - i - 1];
    }
    for(byte b : mantissaBytes) {
        derStream.write(b);
    }
}
```

The result for 1398101.25 is

```
[9, 15, -128, 20, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53]
```

instead of what it ought to be which is

```
[9, 5, -128, -2, 85, 85, 85]
```

Comment: I edited for my change to base 16 on the call toUnsignedString(mantissa, 16).

Comment: I suggest you ask some specific questions and add some comments that explain what you are doing.  It isn't very obvious to me how you are following the DER spec here.  One thing that stands out - what are you doing with toUnsignedString there?  I am not sure why you are converting the mantissa to a string representation, and then taking those CHARACTERS and encoding the corresponding bytes.

Comment: You should be encoding using base 2.  Maybe you are trying to do base 10.  I have no idea.

Comment: Better `getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)` but at that spot the logic is lost. There are some Long.reverse and reverseBytes. There is ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using characters (which BER/DER uses only for base=10) not bits, as commented by Kevin, and also doing them backwards which makes no sense at all, your errors are:

- the IEEE-then-ISO/IEC floating-point scheme used by Java (and most popular CPUs), like most others, has the implied binary/radix point at the left of the 'mantissa' (better, significand), not the right as for BER/DER, and also has a 'hidden' 1-bit to the left of that implied point
- DER (but not BER) requires normalizing the mantissa (except zero, which was already special-cased) so its least significant bit is 1; for base=2 this only requires adjusting the exponent, but 8 or 16 can require a scale factor as well

In addition, you don't need an `ASN1OutputStream` to encode integers, because Java's builtin `BigInteger.toByteArray()` already produces canonical big-endian two's-complement, and you don't actually need to handle exponent lengths greater than 2 octets because they will never occur for IEEE-ISO/IEC values. (They could be needed if you wanted `BigDecimal` values or similar.)

The following code produces the correct and expected value (excluding tag and length):

```
    double d = 1398101.25d;
    ByteArrayOutputStream str = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // for demo, use real output as needed

    long bits = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d);
    int signByte = (int)(bits>>(63-6))&(1<<6) | (1<<7);
    // shift to the correct place to start with, and pre-add bit 8
    int exponent = ((int)(bits>>52)&0x7FF)-(1023+52);
    // don't need to box/unbox to do arithmetic
    long mantissa = (bits&0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) | (1L<<52);
    // add the hidden bit
    while( (mantissa&1)==0 ){ mantissa>>=1; exponent++; }
    // normalize
    byte[] exptbytes = BigInteger.valueOf(exponent).toByteArray();
    if(exptbytes.length<3) str.write(signByte|(exptbytes.length-1)); 
    else{ str.write(signByte|3); str.write(exptbytes.length); }
    // only the if branch is actually needed 
    str.write (exptbytes);
    str.write (BigInteger.valueOf(mantissa/*>>scale*/).toByteArray());

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.toByteArray()));
    // for demo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got the test passing and now my port of Squeak's Cryptography ASN1 framework to Java is complete. Now to advance on ParrotTalk, my 2048-bit key negotiated connection framework.

Comment: I have to share my news somewhere. Here is as good a place as any as you helped complete my ASN1 encoder.

Comment: I finished getting my rendezvous working, then dove into my cipher, ivSequence and mac and got all that working. I now have a Squeak version, a Pharo version and a Java version talking my ParrotTalk Protocol [1]. Data encrypted and decrypts in all three systems after the same ASN.1 based rendezvous and exchange of RSA publicKeys, cipher and encoder selection, diffie hellman parameter and signature of traffic. It completes and builds an encipherment stack with MAC immigration, decryption, MAC customs validation, decoding and event broadcast from the Session of arriving data.

Comment: Hello world passes within each implementation. Now I will see if I can get data passing between Pharo and Java.

Comment: I fixed Java implementation to sign just the asn1 encoded headers that have passed. Signatures match in Pharo/Squeak. Still an issue in Java sending a Bye back. And so it goes... Pharo/Squeak/Java is coming together.

Comment: I changed some of the header types to align between these languages. It now works, I am passing encrypted data between Squeak/Pharo and Java. Check it out.